# Clonezilla clone HDD to smaller SSD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ssd

I have HDD with three partitions:
Hidden: Asus Recovery Partition ~ 22GB
C: Windows 7 ~ 160GB
D: Some data ~ 260GB

I have new SSD 250GB and what I want is a clone of Hidden partition and C: to my new SSD. D: partition is not important and I dont want it, but it has some important data, so I cant delete it.

I downloaded Clonezilla, LIVECD, should I choose this option for each partition part_to_local_part ?

It is important that SSD should boot as the HDD does..

Or maybe I should create image of the whole 500GB drive and then edit the image (delete D partition somehow) and then load data to SSD ? Parted Magic could do that?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish your goals, including booting, you're wanting to do two things.  One is to copy the first two partitions.  The other thing you're seeking to do is to copy the boot process.  With a traditional MBR format, which you might be using, the boot process is contained in first 512 bytes of a disk, which is called the MBR.  This is not part of either of those partitions.  (The other part of the boot process is contained in the partitions that get copied over.)

If you're using GPT, then the same concepts apply, although the boot sequence will involve more than just the first 512 bytes of the disk.  Some tools work better with GPT than others.

You might be easiest to just do a complete image copy.  Of course, the copy will fail since you'll run out of space, but that could simply result in a corrupt partial copy of the third partition, which you could then delete.

Note that instead of trying to copy the existing boot sequence, you might find it easier to just re-create it.  Start by just focusing on getting the partitions copied, and making sure that they were correctly written to disk.  Then, re-enable booting (by re-enabling the boot code... on MBR disks this was often described as re-installing the MBR).  With Windows 7, BCDEdit may be useful for this.

Comment: Ok cloning with Clonezilla is finished. I have two partitions cloned. When I turn on laptop it says disk error. I guess BCDEdit is next step however I dont want to destroy booting in HDD, SSD doesnt work so how to run BCDEdit? In BCDEdit I can change boot drive but if I do it on HDD, I will destroy HDD booting..

Comment: One option may be to use another boot disk (like the Windows installation disk), preferably with the hard drive unplugged.  (If that's really undesirable, maybe disabling it in the BIOS, although I would be a bit less trustful of that approach.)  If you want specific software details, I suggest letting us know what kind of disk layout are you working with?  (MBR-based or GPT?)

Comment: Now I am writing from my second laptop, where I have Ubuntu, nevermind, just dont think my Windows work :)

I have Win7 recovery DVD (not istnallation) but automatic repair doesnt work. I can open command prompt and check what is needed. 
HDD is detached, SSD is attached to SATA slot. 

Diskpart: list disk: GPT column is empty so I quest it is MBR?

Comment: I also downloaded Win7 installation for repairing purposes. I dont want to install from it as it propably wont work with my product key from to bottom of my laptop. I use System repair after boot from installation ISO but it doesnt work, still cannot boot. I wonder why I have Windows on D partition and C is recovery partition, on HDD I have os on C partiion and Recovery is without any label.

Comment: After cloning D partition to another hard drive (Touro 1TB) everything went flawlessly withc Clozilla and device to device cloning and without checking disk size.